# Get PHP to read my postgres select statement?

Tags: php, postgresql, sql

I have an application that was built by someone else that I need to edit.  There is an area of code that I cannot find the right syntax for ... can someone please help.

The select statement in POSTGRES goes like this:

```
SELECT collection|| '/' ||color AS collection
FROM table
WHERE series = 'random number' <-- this is controlled by an array in the php
```

in the php the existing code looks like this:

```
$tableName = $db->getOne('SELECT collection FROM item_series WHERE series = ?', array($series['marriage_1']));
}else{$tableName = $series['marriage_1'];}
```

I have tried this, but it is not working:

```
$tableName = $db->getOne('SELECT collection, ".'/'.", color AS collection FROM item_series WHERE series = ?', array($series['marriage_1']));
}else{
$tableName = $series['marriage_1'];}
```

Please help I have looked for an answer to this for hours!

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be this?

```
$db->getOne('select collection || \'/\' || color as collection ...', ...);
```

Or this?

```
$db->getOne("select collection || '/' || color as collection ...", ...);
```

Your attempt:

```
'SELECT collection, ".'/'.", color AS collection FROM item_series WHERE series = ?'
```

would end this SQL to the database:

```
SELECT collection, "/", color AS collection FROM item_series ...
```

and PostgreSQL wouldn't be upset with you for trying to use double quotes for a string literal, it would think you were trying to access a column called `/`. Besides, you want to concatenate and you want to use the `||` SQL operator for that.